# Normalizers of subgroups of $p$-groups. Is my proof correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation, p-groups

I am trying to learn the proof techniques of group theory, and I tried to prove the following theorem (with some help from the book). Could you please tell me if my proof is correct, and give any suggestions or general comments? Thank you very much.

I have colorized in red the parts where I am slightly shaky. Thanks

> Let $P$ be a $p$- group (so $|P| = p^a$ for some $a > 1$) and suppose $H < P$. Then $H<N_P(H)$.

*Proof:* We use induction on the order of $P$. The theorem is clearly true for $|P| = p^1$. Suppose the theorem is true for $|P| = p^1, p^2, ..., p^{a-1}$. Take a group $P$ of order $p^a$, and take $H < P$. If $Z(P) \not \subseteq H$, then we are done, because $Z(P) \le N_P(H)$. Suppose $Z(P) \subseteq H$, and consider the quotient group $\overline{P} = P / Z(P)$. Since (as I have proved before) the center of $P$ is not trivial, this quotient group is a $p$-group of order strictly less than $p^a$, and therefore it satisfies the induction hypothesis. Thus there exists an $\overline{x} \in \overline {P}$ with $\overline{x} \not \in \overline H$ such that 
$$\overline{x} \overline {H} \overline {x^{-1}} = \overline{H}.$$
$\color{red}{\text{The condition } \overline {x} \not \in \overline{H} \text{implies that } x \not \in H}$.

Take any $h \in H$. We have $\overline {x} \overline {h} \overline{x^{-1}} = \overline{h'}$ for some $h' \in H$, $\color{red}{\text{which implies that } xhx^{-1} \in H}$.

Since $h$ was arbitrary above, we have that $xhx^{-1} \in H$ for all $h \in H$, and therefore $x \in N_P(H)$ but $x \not \in H$, as desired.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun This theorem is in Dummit and Foote, section 6.1. I tried to read as little of the proof as possible before trying to finish it on my own

Comment: I am not reading your proof but just let you know, this is true for all nilpotent groups.

Comment: @Bach Ok thanks

Comment: @Ovi Actually you can directly jump to the four equivalent statements of nilpotent groups in Dummit and Foote.

Comment: @Bach Ah I may do that if I am low on time, but I am trying to learn the proof techniques of group theory, so I think going through more theorems (even if redundant) is good

Comment: Your proof is correct, since $\overline{x} \notin \overline{H}$ is equivalent to $x \notin HZ(P)$. Since $Z(P) \subseteq H$ this amounts to $x \notin H$. Similar reasoning for you second statement in red.

Comment: @NickyHekster Thanks!